# ExtJS deep data binding

Tags: extjs, data-binding, binding, extjs5

i have question about extJs deep data binding. I have one component data binded to object from viewModel. And i want to change one property of that object and update component tpl. Extjs don't work like this, he is update component only when whole object from viewModel is changed. I see that is deep:true property for that case, but i dont know how to use it. Where to put deep property in that code.

```
           {
            xtype: 'component',
            bind: {
                data: '{someObject}'
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having more info would help but you use the deep config like so.

```
bind: {
    data: {
        bindTo: '{someObject}',
        deep: true
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work for me. Now i can update just one property in bind-ed object and component will render again. Tnx